Обрабатывает media_group только для одного аккаунта aiogram 2
Проблема в том что при отправке двух или более фото с одного аккаунта боту работает все корректно, если отправляется с другого аккаунта то он обрабатывает только одно фото
Логи:
[{"media": "AgACAgQAAxkBAAMEZvK10C0ljKKEStmU-sLohx8SJFAAAl7BMRvpipBTBPWsZkaoKjoBAAMCAAN4AAM2BA", "type": "photo", "parse_mode": "html"}, {"media": "AgACAgQAAxkBAAMFZvK10PnPj4ov6-DV-4EMbhcRZRQAAl_BMRvpipBTGL6gqJAlM7oBAAMCAAN4AAM2BA", "type": "photo", "parse_mode": "html"}]
[{"media": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAMNZvK196l4ZxmenHpRMgvtWfCag5MAArf9MRsdQJhLJsktX71EAgkBAAMCAAN4AAM2BA", "type": "photo", "parse_mode": "html"}]
Сам код:
class AlbumMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    """This middleware is for capturing media groups."""

    album_data: dict = {}
def __init__(self, latency: Union[int, float] = 0.01):
    """
    You can provide custom latency to make sure
    albums are handled properly in highload.
    """
    self.latency = latency
    super().__init__()

async def on_process_message(self, message: types.Message, data: dict):
    if not message.media_group_id:
        return

    try:
        self.album_data[message.media_group_id].append(message)
        raise CancelHandler()  # Tell aiogram to cancel handler for this group element
    except KeyError:
        self.album_data[message.media_group_id] = [message]
        await asyncio.sleep(self.latency)

        message.conf["is_last"] = True
        data["album"] = self.album_data[message.media_group_id]

async def on_post_process_message(self, message: types.Message, result: dict, data: dict):
    """Clean up after handling our album."""
    if message.media_group_id and message.conf.get("is_last"):
        del self.album_data[message.media_group_id]


async def create_media_group(album: List[types.Message]):
    media_group = types.MediaGroup()
    for obj in album:
        file_id = obj.photo[-1].file_id if obj.photo else obj[obj.content_type].file_id
        media_group.attach({"media": file_id, "type": obj.content_type})
    return media_group


@dp.message_handler(state=Mailing.waiting_for_mailing, content_types=types.ContentTypes.ANY)
async def set_mailing(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext, album: List[types.Message] = None):
    file, caption, type = '', '', ''
    
    if message.text:
        caption, type = message.text, 'text'

    elif message.media_group_id:
        file, type = await create_media_group(album), 'media_group'

